# Laravel Route failing: Receiving PHP Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in routes.php on line 14

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am getting the following error when trying to display my site:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Route' not found in
>   /home/jillumin/public_html/muse/app/routes.php on line 14

Route looks like the following:

```
Route::resource('ideas','IdeaController');
```

The controller is here:

```
class Idea_Controller extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       //get all the ideas
       $ideas =  idea::all();

       // load the view and pass the ideas
        return View::make('muse.index');

    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You've either name-spaced your routes.php file or disabled the alias in config/app.php for Route. You could also try running 'composer dump' to rebuild Composers autoload_classmap.php.