# Laravel 5 class

Tags: php, laravel

I installed **laravel 5.1** on my **windows 7**, after that i tried to open `blog/app/Htttp/routes.php`.Now there's a error on my browser saying

> "Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_1\blog\app\Http\routes.php on line 14".

How do i remove this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743889/laravel-route-failing-receiving-php-fatal-error-class-route-not-found-in-rou

Comment: open routes.php where?

Comment: in my web browser google chrome.

Comment: that is because you dont serve any of those files. The only php file the webserver should even have access to is the index.php file that is in public. That is the frontloader for the entire application.

Comment: Yeah so what should i do to make it work?

Comment: You are not supposed to open PHP files in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Before a `class` is available in `PHP` you will need to require/include it. As you have opened up the file directly in the browser, the laravel application is not bootstrapped and none of the dependencies are loaded to be used.

If you open up `public/index.php`, you will find a line that says

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
// this later calls composer autoload which compiles a file 
// that includes all the classes that you have specified in your `composer.json`.
```

Now that you have opened the file directly, non of the classes are included and hence you get the error.

I am not sure about your intentions for opening that file directly in the browser. I can only suggest you that the error is expected and you should go through the `public/index.php` for the application to work properly.